# listview onclick after rotate to landscape

Tags: android, listview, landscape

When I rotate screen to landscape and when I want to select an object from my custom  listview is an exception, but when screen is in portrait everything is ok.

After rotate to landscape and click on list view item activity throws an exception.

---

MainActivity:

```
 WeatherAdapter adapter;
            ListView view;
            Button btn;
            /* Row item */
            View h;
            Setting set;

        TextView u,kz;
        RelativeLayout lay;

        Weather selected;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.d("onCreate()",(" "  + set.last).toString());
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gonext);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

        kz = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        view = new ListView(this);       

        adapter = new WeatherAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_view_item_row, set.weather_data);

        view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        /*
        View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_view_header_row, null);
        view.addHeaderView(header);
       */
        view.setAdapter(adapter);

     view.setOnItemClickListener(this);
     //view.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
       if(set.last != -1){
           View cc = view.getChildAt(set.last);
           Log.d("Choosed",("last = " + set.last).toString());
            RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) cc.findViewById(R.id.ItemLayout);
            r.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            r.refreshDrawableState();
       }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v.getId() == R.id.gonext){

            selected = new Weather(set.weather_data[set.last]);

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,Choosed_Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("selected_i", selected.icon);
            intent.putExtra("selected_t", selected.title);
            this.startActivity(intent);




        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //h = (View) view.getChildAt((int) arg3);
        if(set.last != -1){
            h = (View) (view.getChildAt(set.last));
            u = (TextView) h.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            lay = (RelativeLayout) h.findViewById(R.id.ItemLayout);
            lay.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            u.setText("FAFAFAF");
            }
        //}
        h = (View) (view.getChildAt((int) arg3));
        u = (TextView) h.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        lay = (RelativeLayout) h.findViewById(R.id.ItemLayout);
        lay.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        u.setText(("siam " + arg2).toString());

        set.last = (int) arg3;

        if(set.last > -1)
            btn.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

WeatherAdapter:

```
public class WeatherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Weather>{



    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;   
    Weather data[] = null;

    public WeatherAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Weather[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        Log.d("WEATHER ADAPETR","Constructor()");
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        WeatherHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new WeatherHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            holder.rL = (RelativeLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.ItemLayout);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Weather weather = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(weather.title);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(weather.icon);
        holder.rL.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        return row;
    }

    static class WeatherHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
        RelativeLayout rL;
    }
}
```

Weather:

```
public class Weather {
    public int icon;
    public String title;

    public Weather(){
        super();
    }
    public Weather(Weather w){
        this.icon = w.icon;
        this.title = w.title;
    }
    public Weather(int icon, String title) {
        super();
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the stack trace + some code, also are you using a custom adapter?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that after rotating the screen the activity is recreated (as normally happens) and on clicking the ListView you try to access an object within the Activity that is no longer valid.

Comment: Could you tell us what Exception your getting? A logcat would be appreciated.